# Yolov4 resizing

Tags: computer-vision, yolov4

Does yolov4 does resizing of images itself during training or we need to resize the images before training? if resizing is required before training then what is the suggested size for resizing?

Comment: Which implementation of YoloV4 are you asking about? Darknet from AlexeyAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yolo-V4 resizes images during training. You don't have to manually resize images beforehand.

It actually resizes images to different dimensions (multiples of 32) randomly at different points of an epoch and adjusts the network accordingly. This enables robust detection of objects of different scales and sizes

Comment: Thanks! appreciated 